# will redirecting of the parent URL affect the children URL?

Tags: seo, redirects

my website has this URL :

(A) http://www.mysite.com/book/name-of-book/12345

This url will show to the detailed information of a book with ID=12345

When user skips the "/12345" part in the url, (i.e. (B) http://www.mysite.com/book/name-of-book ), the user will be redirected (302 redirect) to this page:

(C) http://www.mysite.com/search/name-of-book

which searches all books that contains the word "name, of, book".

As the url (B) is actually the "parent folder" of url (A), so in terms of SEO, will redirecting (B) to (C) cause any negative effect on (A)?

Answer (score 2):

Every URL is independent of another. So if URL B is a redirect it won't affect URL A.

Answer (score 0):

No that wouldn't be an issue, as long as you make sure that the entire path exists. But why is there a redirect there? if he leaves out the 12345 he doesn't have to be redirected, right? If he does have to be redirected, make it a 301 and not a 302.

Comment: Because there may be more than one book named "name-of-book" so we think listing  all the available books (i.e. the search result) would give better user experience.

Comment: Yeah fine with that, just doesn't have to be a redirect, but an immediate 200 on that URL?

Comment: oh...get your point...it sounds good. thx!